# Shivering text with CSS transitions

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I've tried creating a ripple effect on hover over with a button, the only problem I have is that the text shakes/rattles/shivers when I hover over it, I want it to stay still for a smooth transition. Any ideas on how to stop this?

```css
a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .2);
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden;
  margin: 10% auto;
}
p,
span:first-of-type,
span:last-of-type {
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transition: all .3s;
}
span:first-of-type {
  transition-delay: .1s;
  z-index: 1;
}
span:last-of-type {
  transition-delay: .2s;
  z-index: 2;
}
span.cta {
  color: #33C;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: Arial;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  width: 300px;
  display: block;
  transition: color .3s;
  z-index: 3;
}
a:hover p,
a:hover span:first-of-type,
a:hover span:last-of-type {
  width: 110%;
  height: 660%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .2);
}
a:hover span:first-of-type,
a:hover span:last-of-type {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
a:hover p span {
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <p>
    <span></span>
    <span class="cta">Shop the Trend</span>
    <span></span>
  </p>
</a>
```

N.B. It's fine in IE11, it happens in every other browser.

Comment: Why don't you use something like materializecss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...Modified HTML[added button text inside div and applied new class "textCta" to it]

```
<span class="cta"><div class="textCta">Shop the Trend</div></span>
```

CSS

```
.textCta {
    color:#33C;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    font-family:Arial;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
    width: 300px;
    display: block;
    transition: color .3s;
    z-index: 3;
}
```

[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VeyZby)

Answer (score 0):

By deleting the p tags and placing the actual text within a div, I managed to stop the shivering and still keep the background effect the same.

Thanks to Nofi for their help.

```
<a href="#">
    <span></span>
    <div class="cta">Shop the Trend</div>
    <span></span>
</a>
```